# Use AJAX to GET smart_collections.json

Tags: shopify

Within a Shopify store I am making several AJAX calls and only one returns a 401 Unauthorized. The AJAX url is `https://{{key}}:{{password}}@stand-around-creations.myshopify.com/admin/smart_collections.json?limit=250&fields=id,title,handle,image` and it returns this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://stand-around-creations.myshopify.com/admin/smart_collections.json?limit=250&fields=id,title,handle,image. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://stand-around-creations.myshopify.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

I am using a private app with read access only for products, variants and collections. I know this is an authentication issue but how to solve to me isnt really clear. I have never used Basic Auth, OAuth or OAuth 2 and only have a very basic understanding of the concept. I tried searching the Shopify forums for a solution but couldn't find a solution. So how can I solve this issue or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you looking to achieve? It's best to avoid using Ajax with the admin APIs.

Comment: based on the collection navigated to, I am adding collections of particular products in the form of list elements (each collection navigated to will have a different set). So basically I am navigating to a collection with a range of collections from 50 to 120 list elements. The ajax call is to get those collections which is hard coded in a javascript array. This is definitely not the best way to do this but the only way I know of without creating a server application in Django or J2EE. This one call broke as soon as the client launched the site, it worked in the editor.

Comment: I use smart_collections.json to grab the collections I need and store those in the following <li><a href="source to collection"><image src="collection image"><span>title</close all tags>. So the collection navigated to will range from 50 to 120 list elements.

Comment: I read somewhere telling someone to create a public app and not to public the app to the app store. Have the store install the app. Use OAuth to authenticate and then it should work. Not sure if this will work or if their is a simpler solution.

Comment: Check out [Liquid](https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/collections) or the [JavaScript Buy SDK](http://shopify.github.io/js-buy-sdk/). You should not use private app keys or OAuth permanent access tokens in any frontend code where they can be read by the public.

Comment: could you provide an example of how I could do this with Javascript Buy SDK? Setup is straight forward but I don't see anything in the docs for collections.

Comment: Curious to point my basic web scraper at Shopify and the 300,000 shops, and see how many valid API credentials are public. I bet the number is non-zero.

Comment: They provide security features which restricts access to certain features.....for the private app I have read only for products, variants and collections. Everything else is set to no access.....

Comment: So I am stuck with Liquid templating it looks like....